# Silverlight - Is it possible to create UI elements on a background thread?

Tags: c#, multithreading, silverlight, charts

I'm building a line chart control in Silverlight using PolyLineSegment and points. It works just as expected, but the application freezes for a long time when there's too much data that needs to be visualized (too many points). I can't move my code on a separate thread for an obvious reason - it deals with UI elements directly, so when I try to call them from a separate thread it results in exception (even if UI elements are not yet rendered).

Is there any way to create UI elements dynamically on a background thread and then pass them to the UI thread to be rendered? And if not, what would be the possible solution? I'm thinking of creating an Bitmap image instead of actual controls, but there won't be much interactivity in this case.

Comment: What is taking the most time? Is it the actual rendering of the elements, or are you performing a bunch of calculations before creating each one? If it's the latter, you could probably run those calculations on a background thread and then marshal the creation of each element via the `Dispatcher`.

Comment: There are not too many calculations in my code, rather a lot of data. I'm talking about millions of points. Shrinking them is not the best option.

Comment: That makes it much more difficult. If you have millions of points, though, how are they showing on the screen at once? Even at 1024x768 there's < 800K pixels. Are you rendering off-screen in a scroll viewer? If so, could you virtualize the UI? If not, you're likely coalescing points somehow; could that be done to the data?

Comment: This is a graph of PCM audio data and it basically displays a waveform. The algorithm used to determine each point's {X, Y} location relies on neighbor values. I tried to shrink the array and apply interpolation, but visual result is not very accurate. As for rendering time, it seems that PolyLineSegment translates all the points into one bitmap image, so it doesn't take that much time.

Comment: In my experience it's actually the rendering of the `PolyLineSegment` that takes all the time. Creating 100k points is fast; rendering them is slow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you need to get a faster way of rendering your points.  If you have 800k samples and only say, 800 pixels to display them in you're wasting 1000 points per pixel of calculations if you just load it into a `PolyLineSegment`.

I would revisit 'interpolating' the points (this is really coalescing for your large dataset).  You want to make sure you capture the dynamic range of the function in each pixel correctly:

- Figure out how many pixels wide the graph should be
- Determine how many points per pixel in the X direction
- For each chunk of points:

  - Build a histogram of the points
  - Draw a vertical line from max->min on your graph at the X where these points will map to.  This captures the full range represented in the chunk.

If your points/pixel gets close to 1 you'll want to switch to the easy rendering to give better visual results as well.

Comment: Thank you, I accept this as an answer. I wasn't able to compress the data earlier, because there were two stereo channels in my PCM byte array. After figuring out the structure, however, the rest was pretty straightforward :)

Answer (score 2):

For displaying a waveform (in your case PCM audio data) with "millions of points" you would be better off writing directly to a WritableBitmap. You then have only one render object.

You have already said there is not much processing in your calculations. Trying to use individual UIElements is way too big an overhead (IMHO). Point display is trivial to a bitmap and there are plenty of line drawing algorithms out there, optimised for speed, to do any line segments.

You can plot your points on a background thread and them update an image's ImageSource at the end of the processing to display it.

Comment: I also thought it will be work, but guess what happens when you call WriteableBitmap from background thread? Using Dispatcher.BeginInvoke with synchronization is even slower in this case.

Comment: If the WriteableBitmap is not connected to the UI tree you should not need to be on the UI thread to update raw pixels.

Comment: So what you are saying, is that there's a way to disconnect WriteableBitmap objects from the UI tree? Also, does it work with other controls or just WriteableBitmap?

Comment: Writeable bitmaps are an image source. They are not part of the Visual Tree. Not tried it with other controls, but it probably would work as the only reason they need to be on the UI Thread is for rendering changes to be visible. When you add them they will render whatever is in them.

Answer (score 0):

You certainly can do your compute work on background thread(s) and pass the finished results up to the UI tread with

`Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke`

which is discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4679324/what-is-the-use-of-deployment-current-dispatcher-begininvoke)

Comment: Thanks, but it's not an option. Most of the work is UI generation, not the calculations.